# How can I force an exception or error in WinSCP NET assembly for testing purposes?

Tags: winscp-net

I am using the WinSCP NET assembly to synchronize directories. I have added

```
 session.QueryReceived += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        //Write line to Error Log
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(sLogPath + sErrorLogName))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "," + e.Message);
                        }

                        //Write line to Sync Log
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(sLogPath + sLogFileName))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(",Error", "", e.Message, "");
                        }

                        //Continue
                        e.Continue();
                    };
```

to capture any errors without stopping the entire process. I log those errors for later review. I am not currently getting any errors in the sync, but I would like to test my logging process. Is there any way to afke/force an error in the sync process?

Thanks!

Comment: You can for example lock one of the local files.

Comment: Should have said: 
"Ok, I tried that, but it did NOT error out. Just now I realized that I did not change the timestamp on that file, so it was not included in the sync. Thanks!" Now that I changed the timestamp and held the file open, it DID error out. Thanks again!